# Boolean Satements

Tags: java, boolean, fibonacci

```
public class A4work
{
    private static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return n;
        }
        {
            return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isAfibonacci(int a) {
        int x = 0; //sequence number
        int c = 0;  //number in fib sequence
        while (a <= c) {
            c = fibonacci(x);
            x++;
        }

        if (a == c) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)   //called a method signiture
    {
        System.out.println("The 5th Square pyramidal number is " + isAfibonacci(3));
    }
}
```

I think I have the code right, but it keeps on returning false. I'm using it to decide if a number is in the fib sequence or not.
      Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If your input `a` is 5, for example, you will have:

```
int c = 0;  //number in fib sequence
while (a <= c) { ... }
```

The `while` loop will never run since `5 <= 0` is false. So `a == c` will always be false for any `a` greater than zero.

I think you want to stop iterating when `c` is greater than or equal to `a`, so the correct condition would be

```
while (c < a) { ... }
```

Comment: SO how would I change that?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `System.out.println("The 5th Square pyramidal number is "+ isAfibonacci(3) );`, `a` in your `isAfibonacci();` method becomes 3. Now look at your code knowing that.

```
    while(3 <= 0) //replaced a with 3 here and c with 0 for visualization
      {
       ...
       }
```

A non-negative, non-zero integer will never be less than or equal to 0, therefore, will always result in false.

Comment: I changed it to greater and I'm still getting false. Is it even possible to put loops inside boolean statements or no?